# What is proguard.txt at the libs/ folder of an Android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, proguard

The role of proguard.cfg at the **root** of an Android project is pretty clear, as it is explained in this [Proguard Improvements](http://tools.android.com/recent/proguardimprovements) post. It is a file that's edited and maintained by the project developer and so far so good.

But I just noticed that there is another file with the same basename (but different extension), `proguard.txt` that is auto-generated by the Eclipse+Adt build system and placed in the `libs/` subdirectory of the project.

This file is auto-created even if the project is never exported (i.e. into a release APK).

What is the purpose of this file?

Is it some type of caching to speed up APK generation when export is eventually performed?

Can it be used for debug purposes?

Comment: Take a look here: [ProGuard Improvements](http://tools.android.com/recent/proguardimprovements)

Comment: @vikram If you re-read my original post, you will notice that I gave exactly the same link... which has no reference whatsoever to `libs/` and thus doesn't really answer my questions about `proguard.txt`. I am still curious as to what this file is. Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Ahh, I guess I opened the link(new tab) you had given, kept on reading your post, and later thought I found something that can help you. Or, may be not. In any case, I screwed up. Out of ideas on this one. Is this happening with one of your projects or several?

Comment: @vikram All of my projects produce that `libs/proguard.txt`. It is not mentioned anywhere in the ProGuard docs I have read so far. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

produard-projectname.txt is renamed version of proguard.cfg. The filename renamed with [ADT 17](http://tools.android.com/recent/proguardimprovements)

proguard.txt file is required to run Proguard tool. It is contains default config values.

To optimize .apk file you should make changes on the this file. Such as, enabling logging etc.